# Need to fix error with c++ code - related to strcpy

Tags: c++

I have an error here with my code in `strcpy`.

I declared name , company , type , color and state as string

```
    void SaveList(void)
{
    ofstream pFile;
    pFile.open("Car.dat",ios::binary);
    if(pFile==NULL)
        {
            cout<<"Cannot Open File \n updated Data not saved into file\n\n";
            exit(0);
        }

    struct Car_F  NF; // structure variable to hold data for file
    struct Car *CURR;
         for (CURR = HEAD ; CURR != HEAD ; CURR = CURR->forw )
         {  // copy record from linked list into file record structure
            NF.ID=CURR->ID;
            strcpy(NF.name,CURR->name);
            strcpy(NF.Company_of_car,CURR ->Company_of_car);
            strcpy(NF.type_of_car,CURR ->type_of_car);
            strcpy(NF.color_of_car,CURR ->color_of_car);
            NF.model_of_car = CURR->model_of_car;
            NF.price_of_car = CURR->price_of_car;
            strcpy(NF.state_of_car,CURR ->state_of_car);


             pFile.write((char*) &NF,sizeof(NF)); // write record into file
         }
        pFile.close();

}
```

Can somebody help me out please. I will be really happy

Comment: Not without an [SSCCE](http://www,sscce.org) as well as a clear problem statement.

Comment: Please post error messages so we can help you better.  Also, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get better answers

Comment: What do you mean by "I have an error"? What kind of error? Does it fail to compile? Does it compile and crash at runtime? Does it run and give you output other than what you expected? Please update your question with specific information.

Comment: There's very little c++ in this code.

Comment: What are the Car_F and Car structs? And why are you using strcpy?

Comment: The strcpy function does not copy strings. It copies char arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The `strcpy` function is a C function that operates on `char*` character arrays (which is what C uses as strings). See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

C++ string objects are completely different, and remove the need for calling C string functions. See here for a list of C++ string member functions: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

The `operator=` string assignment is what you're after. For a first step in fixing this, **I would replace the `strcpy(NF.name,CURR->name);` with `NF.name = CURR->name;`** (and so on). C++ objects make it look a lot more simpler and natural, through the use of the operator function syntax.

Also, why are you copying the record completely before writing it out? Is that necessary? There are a number of other things that are not ideal with the code, such as casting the struct to a `char*` to write out. I would suggest studying some example code for `iostream` to see how that is used to serialise (write out and read in) objects.